# Add add-on (extra) product in Shopify product page as a dropdown

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I want to add an add-on product to Shopify's product page as a dropdown. If the customer selects the add-on products, it adds it to the cart and the customer is redirected there.

For example, if the product page has a T-shirt, the add-on dropdown would be a cap. When clicking "Add to cart", the two are added to the cart if the add-on product is selected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide us with code of what have you tried on your own until this point?

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox makes more sense in your use case better than a drop down. What you need to do is:

- If the addon product checkbox is checked then you need to override the "add to cart" button behaviour or the product form submit, it depends if the form is ajaxified or not.
- Then you are going to have to use [Shopify store Ajax API](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api) to add the two products, you won't be able to add the two products in one request to you are going to have to add one then add the other product when the first request is a success, then once its a success you get to redirect to cart page.

I didn't get into implementation details this is just a high level of what needs to be done, if you get stuck please share the code that you are working with so you may get some more help.

Good luck!